# PPPoE Authentication Issues

Tags: router, modem, tomato, pppoe, vdsl

So I have a R7000 running Advanced Tomato connected to a Technicolor TG589vac setup in bridge mode. Connecting directly to the technicolor I can do the PPPoE connection and have connectivity since It's already configured with VLAN ID 7 (my ISP requirement - 1und1).

However when setting up the WAN on the R7000 with the same credentials i get the following:

```
Jan  1 01:10:36 unknown daemon.info pppd[4977]: Starting link
Jan  1 01:10:36 unknown daemon.info pppd[4977]: PPP session is 2734 (0xaae)
Jan  1 01:10:36 unknown daemon.warn pppd[4977]: Connected to 00:30:88:1f:31:72 via interface vlan2
Jan  1 01:10:36 unknown daemon.notice pppd[4977]: Connect: ppp0 <--> vlan2
Jan  1 01:10:36 unknown daemon.err pppd[4977]: PAP authentication failed
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well then add the answer yourself. With the specific instructions you used to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the password, since it had "special chars" for example % the router was truncating the password at the first occurrence. Thankfully I can change the PW and it worked!